# Solving equation system of complex funtions

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-equations

Does there exist two complex functions $f$ and $g$ satisfy below equation system?
$$
\begin{cases}
f=e^g\\
g=e^f
\end{cases}
$$
What about analytic funtions?

Comment: May the implicit function theorem be of any use?

Comment: @Michael Hoppe, You mean I can separate the equation system into Real and Imaginary parts and then use the implicit function theorem?

Comment: Are there two complex _numbers_ satisfying these equations?

Comment: @Igor Rivin, It's very hard to find these two complex numbers, to find such two complex numbers, we should solve nonlinear equation systems.

Comment: @JameAke : I would also look for two complex numbers solving the equations first.  Maybe you can't find closed forms for them, but try to prove they exist.  You'll need $f = \exp(\exp(f))$ where $f$ is a constant, and $g=\exp(f)$.  Then you have two _constant functions_ that solve your system, and constant functions are analytic.  That's somewhere to start.

Comment: @Stefan Smith: Mybe we can prove the existence of the fixed point of $f(z)=e^{e^{z}}$ by fixed point theory.

Comment: @StefanSmith: Not yet, I don't know how to put a bounty exactly. The answer all we know are discrete points, it seems that they couldn't form regions.

Comment: @Jame Ake : under the comments for the question there should be a little box that reads "start a bounty".  If you click on it then the question becomes a "featured question".  If someone offers a really good answer, you can give them a small number of your reputation points.  I have only done this once or twice.  Once I offered a bounty to a question that no one had given me a good answer to, and I got 5-6 good answers after that.

Comment: @Stefan Smith:Thank you for your tips, but I haven't get this privilege.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $z$ be a solution to the equation $z=\exp(z)$, for example $z = -W(-1)$, where $W$ is a branch of the Lambert function. Numerically, one such value is $z \approx 0.3181315052 - 1.337235701 i$. Put $f = g = z$ for a solution to your problem.

Comment: Your answer is very accurate. I'm not very familiar with Lambert function. May you give some references?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

Comment: @mrf : note that if $z$ solves $z = \exp(z)$, so does ${\overline z}$.  Oddly, Maple only gives one solution to the equation, $-W(-1)$.  WolframAlpha gives only two numerical solutions to $z=\exp(\exp(z))$, which look a lot like $-W(-1)$ and its complex conjugate. WolframAlpha gives $-W_n(-1)$ ($n \in \mathbb{Z}$) as the solution set of $z = \exp(z)$ but they do not have a readable definition of what "$W_n$" means.  They called it the generalized Lambert function but I could not find a definition for it on their site.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a partial answer: if there exist analytic functions $f$ and $g$ satisfying the equations, they must be constants.  Suppose the equations are satisfied by analytic functions.  Then
$f'=e^g g',\ g' = e^f f' = e^{f+g}g'$,  so $g'(e^{f+g}-1)=0$.  If $g'=0$, then $g$ is constant and so is $f$.  If  $e^{f+g}-1=0$, then since $f+g$ is analytic (and continuous), $f+g$ must be constant, say, $f+g=c$.  Then $f'=-g'$, so $f'=e^g g' = -g'$, $g'(e^g + 1)=0$, and either $g$ and $f$ are constants, or $e^g = -1$.  If $e^g =-1$, then, since $g$ is continuous, $g$ must be constant, and so is $f$.

Now it remains to prove that there exists a constant pair of solutions $f, g$.

Comment: You have proved that if $f$ and $g$ are analytic functions then they must be constants. I think this is the key for the case of analytic funtions.

Comment: $f=e^g=-1$ doesn't satisfy the equation system. If $e^{f+g}=1$ then $fg=1$, so $fe^f=1$, so $f=W(1)$.

Comment: When $f=W(1)$, $W(1)=e^{e^{W(1)}}$ should be satisfied, which means $W(1)e^{W(1)}=e^{W(1)}e^{e^{W(1)}}=1$, then $W(1)=e^{W(1)}$ established, this means $W(1)=-W(-1)$.

Comment: @JameAke : much remains unknown.  All we know is what I proved above, and two particular constant solutions: $f=g=-W(-1)$, and $f=g={\overline {-W(-1)}}$.  Since you've accepted a solution, you might consider posing a new question asking for a complete solution.  Of course you should mention what was already proven in these two answers.  I probably can't solve it but I'm curious about the problem.

Comment: If $f=e^g=-1$, then $g=e^f=e^{-1}$, which means $e^{e^{-1}}=-1$, It's impossible. whatever, $f^{\prime}=g^{\prime}=0$ has been proved by you.

Answer (score 0):

Merging the equation system, we get $f=e^{e^f}$. Mutiplying at both sides of this equation by $e^f$, i.e., $fe^f=e^fe^{e^f}$, let $fe^f=\zeta$, then $f=W(\zeta)$ and $g=e^f=W(\zeta)$, $f$ and $g$ maybe belong to different branch of $W(\zeta)$.